# Noise as a source of information?

Tags: signal, signal-processing

I was studying a book on signals and systems where it says that noise disturbances which interfere with the transmitted signals are a source of information. And the original signals are not. It mentions that higher the uncertainty in the signal transmitted, more is the information.
How can an unwanted disturbance which has no link to the signal being transmitted be so important?

> The higher the uncertainty about a signal(or message) to be received, higher is the information content. If a message to be received is specified beforehand (i.e., it is known beforehand), it has no uncertainty and, consequently, cannot convey any information.

-Principles Of Communication modern digital and analog communication systems by BP lathi

Comment: Please provide a citation

Comment: @EugeneSh. I added a citation

Comment: Here is an intuitive example of where this may be the case  When I see 60hz noise in a signal that is a lot of information about what is going on :) if it shows up every other day, you can likely predict that this is a cleaning crew running a vacuum cleaner. See! Information. One time we ran a sensitive experiment that was simultaneously an amazing instrument at telling us the exact local train schedule by following the noise amplitude.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory) - You might wanna read this.

Comment: @crasic thanks for the examples!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The provided quote is not related to noise but to information entropy.
Consider a repeated signal that always reads "Hello world!", and never changes. The receiver of the signal knows it will always read this way. Therefore even without looking at it he will know what it is. So there is no information conveyed by this signal to the receiver.

On the other hand, consider the signal is encoding a fair coin toss outcomes. This one will be maximally uncertain to the receiver (indistinguishable from binary white noise), but it will convey the full information about the remote system (that is the full history of the experiment outcomes).